# Send and Receive SMS using Twilio on iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, twilio

I am using the Twilio API for calls and SMS. I'm unable to send SMS.

1. How can I enable my Twilio number for sending or receiving sms?
2. Please share with me any helping material for sending or receiving sms, like a tutorial or any code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the Twilio iPhone SDK doesn't allow sending or receiving SMS. To send SMS, you can make an HTTP request to the Twilio API, authenticated with your Account Sid and Auth Token, per the instructions at www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms. There's a quickstart tutorial here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest.